# angularjs sub-controller - accessing variables

Tags: angularjs

Assume I have the following:

```
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <p>{{person.name}}</p>
        <div>[LOTS OF COMPLICATED DATA RELATED TO A PERSON THAT I NEED TO ORGANIZE IN A CONTROLLER]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then I have two controllers

```
app.controller('PeopleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){ $scope.people = [etc, etc, etc ];}];
app.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){ HOW DO I ACCESS THE PERSON OBJECT IN THIS CONTROLLER? }];
```

In the above PersonCtrl, how do I access the "person" object referred to in ng-repeat?

Comment: please reread. There is no controller repeating in a controller of itself. PeopleCtrl and PersonCtrl are two different controllers. - sorry this was for a previous comment that has been deleted.

Comment: in the person controller you can filter your data $scope.person.name = $filter('my',$scope.person.name)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access it under `$scope.person` in the `PersonCtl`. Nested scopes inherit from their upper scope.

See an example at http://plnkr.co/edit/EeFOoUEagmsIHL3XlUBx?p=preview:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <p>
          First Name: {{person.firstName}}<br/>
          Last Name: {{person.lastName}}
        </p>

        <div>
          Full Name (from <code>PersonCtrl</code>): {{person.fullName}}
        </div>
        <hr>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})
.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    { id: '0', lastName: 'White', firstName: 'Walt'},
    { id: '1', lastName: 'Black', firstName: 'Hank'}
  ];
})
.controller('PersonCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('PersonCtrl');
  console.log($scope.person);

  $scope.person.fullName = $scope.person.lastName + ', ' + $scope.person.firstName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.name;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be available under the same name as the parent controller. To see what variables have been inherited simply go into the child controller and console.log($scope) this is an object and in the debugger console you can expand it and see if you have set up your inheritance correctly.

As controllers inherit from each other using prototypical inheritance they will look further up the chain for the name if it it not found on their current scope.

Here is a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WwZC8tMW0swjKDAS7n4B

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.people = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Steve'}, {name: 'Jim'}]
 })

.controller('PersonCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log($scope.people)
 });
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
          <p>{{person.name}}</p>
          <div>[LOTS OF COMPLICATED DATA RELATED TO A PERSON THAT I NEED TO ORGANIZE IN A CONTROLLER]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```